# How to create a service that intercepts SMS's without interrupting the native process

Tags: android, sms

I would like to create a service to get an SMS and write it to a file without interrupting the native process of handling an SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific? Do you want to create your own service? Do you want to receive SMS and write that SMS to a file?

#### 1st approach

In you application register Broadcast in Manifest.
Never unregister that broadcast.

Once you receive your broadcast in onreceive() write to a file.

#### 2nd approach

Create a service and in that service register a broadcast
Once you receive ur broadcast in onreceive() write to a file.

Note: don't unregister your broadcast in onDestroy() of your Service. Keep it alive.

You can check this link:

http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android